# How to delete continuously delete text in a TextFormField when the backspace is kept down?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, backspace

I got a `TextFormField` controlled by a `TextEditingController`. I have found no way to remove continuously, one by one, all the characters on the field if the user keeps the backspace pressed on mobile.

The behavior should be similar to what you would expect when writing an email, or text in a document, etc.

Comment: Did you find any solution?